# 'No apps connected. Sending "reload" to all React Native apps failed. Make sure your app is running in the simulator or on a phone connected via USB.'

Tags: ios, react-native, metro-bundler, react-native-cli

My React Native application running on a physical device has some problems.

The Metro bundler console gives a warning :

```
warn No apps connected. Sending "reload" to all React Native apps failed.
Make sure your app is running in the simulator or on a phone connected via USB.
```

This causes a connection problem on the iOS device.

When I try to reload my React Native application from the [React Native Debugger](https://instamobile.io/mobile-tools/react-native-debugger), it gives the above warning and I cannot debug my code in Chrome. 
This happens on a physical device. When I work with an iOS simulator, there is no problem.

**Note:** my phone and MacBook are on the *same* Wi-Fi network.
So, the problem is not related to using different networks.

###### Versions

- react-native: 0.62.2,
- iOS: 13.6

Comment: It is happening to me but in iOS simulator... and ofcourse they are on same network, my xcode scheme is also set to debug, any solution to this?

Comment: @dev1ce same with me. I can run it fine on my iPhone through the QR code but the simulator just opens the iPhone home screen and not the app

Answer (score 72):

**⚠️ For iOS users :**

Check that your build target is Debug :

Xcode Product => Scheme => Edit Scheme => Debug (and not release ! )

**⚠️ For Android users :**

I have found a solution that I posted on github.
Not the best but it could be useful:

**First**, you have to open `MainApplication.java`
and remove `import com.facebook.react.BuildConfig;`

Next, follow these steps :

```
    # Reset metro bundler cache : 
    `npx react-native start --reset-cache`
        
    # Remove Android assets cache : 
    `cd android && ./gradlew clean`
        
    # Relaunch metro server : 
    `npx react-native run-android`
```

And see the magic

See here :
https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/29396

Comment: you saved my day. Thanks a lot.

Comment: That did not help.

Comment: where  MainApplication.java file located is?

Comment: @MujahidulIslam here : `android/app/src/main/java/com/<projectName>/<packageName>/MainApplication.java` (side to MainActivity.java)

If ur using VisualCode, you can use ctrl+p and typing the filename :)

Comment: @Azylaans how to find it in vs code because just cntrl+p is not working

Comment: Thanks `cd android && ./gradlew clean` command worked

Comment: Thanks!, This fix my issue 

Android SDK - Required for building and installing your app on Android
   - Versions found: N/A
   - Version supported: 33.0.0

Comment: This has to be accepted as correct answer  

Comment: It makes not that much sense. At least removing one import is strange without changing other code (won't mention in my case there is no that line at all). Could someone explain what should happen?

Answer (score 28):

Running this worked for me for a **Physical Android Device**.

```
adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081
```

or

```
npm run android-connect
```

If you face an error saying 'More than two devices are running', make sure that the emulators like BlueStacks are not running.

Comment: `adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081` did the trick for me. useful since sometimes my physical android device seems to lose connection. this is instant fix, as opposed to cleaning gradle and rebuilding android

Comment: Usually, if I unplug the USB from my physical device, I would have to run `react-native `run-android` to make Metro connect which requires rebuilding the app. But thanks to you, running ADB reverses as above did the trick without having to rebuild, thanks!

Answer (score 27):

Your iPhone has to be connected to the same network (WiFi for example) as your Mac, because they have to communicate with each other ([React Native Doc](https://reactnative.dev/docs/debugging#debugging-on-a-device-with-chrome-developer-tools)).

If it's already the case, then fill in the **DCHP** server manually on your iPhone and Mac, using Google's server (*8.8.8.8*), because it could be due to DHCP problems.

You may need to disconnect and reconnect to your Wifi.

Answer (score 16):

For me I need to set the bundler location in my app from "localhost:8081" to "192.168.1.XX:8081" which is my computer's local IP address where Metro bundler runs on and the port is 8081.

If you don't know which port your bundler runs on you can specify it as a parameter like:

```
npx react-native start --port 8081
```

Then you need to specify the location in your development app. To do that:

- Shake your device
- Click change bundle location (I am on RN 0.64 it may differ in yours)
- Give the bundler location of your computer's IP and port where Metro bundler runs on like:

[image: Bundle Location Change Dialog]

and they started to communicate with each other.

Comment: This was exactly the case and i don't know why but application set its bundle location to `localhost:8081` in emulator device and the app was requesting js content from virtual device's localhost and that was the issue that causes the rapid disconnects. I changed the bundle location to `my-host-ip:8081` in the test app and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 10):

My problem was that I was not connected to the same WiFi on my Mac and Iphone.I turned the wifi off and back on on both devices, and made sure both the mac and Iphone was connected to the same WiFi. Annoying, but true!

Answer (score 7):

Your iPhone & mac must be connected to the same network. If both device connected to same network you must check local network availability for your app. (this happened to me on a iOS 14.0 running device).

**check local network - iOS 14**
Settings -> Privacy -> Local Network

Answer (score 6):

On Android, this may also happen due to a problem with the network security config. If you do use the network security config, try removing the line `android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"` from `AndroidManifest.xml`

Comment: This answer saving my day! Thank you...

Answer (score 4):

I work on **IOS environment, testing on an IPad** that is USB connected.

I managed to fix this issue by adding the bundler address  (127.0.0.1) in the ipad to reconnect

***Shake the device (opens react native debug menu) > Configure Bundler > "127.0.0.1" in the first field***

Hope this helps someone !

Answer (score 2):

My problem was that the emulator I was using had `airplane mode` turned on (because I tested related functionality). The problem resolved when I turned it off, thus enabling network to operate as usual.

Answer (score 2):

My problem is that the device is not connected to the internet. Throws the error. Try connecting stable internet connection.

Answer (score 2):

When I remove `network_security_config.xml` and remove the following:

```
  `android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"`
```

It works

Comment: Please provide more details how this solves the problem.

Answer (score 1):

What did the trick for me was the following:
In Xcode go to Debug/Detach from YourAppName
Then reattach it by going to Debug/Attach to Process, select your app from the list (usually the first entry at the top).

Comment: This works for me too sometimes, but the apps are listed alphabetically (I think it shows you the list of every process running on the app.

Answer (score 1):

I tried everything and after running

```
adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081
yarn android
```

it worked.

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me in this scenario was these steps

- run server with --reset-cache
- run npx jetify
- open the project in adroid studio
- go to refactor -> Migrate to AndroidX (this was the step that i was missing earlier)
- start your emulator
- run the app from android studio and it should work

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes it's a firewall / router issue - see if that's your problem:

1. Find out the local IP address of your computer (where your Metro bundler / server is running).
2. Open a browser from your phone.
3. Open the IP address from #1 with port 8081 (e.g. `http://192.168.0.42:8081`).

If it's not loading -> it's a firewall / router issue.
A simple solution would be to connect the computer to the phone's hotspot.

Comment: I was running into an issue where I was connected to a public network and I had to use a physical device (iOS) to test. Connecting my mac to my phone's network allowed the Metro to communicate properly.

Comment: Mine behaves the same whether connected to vpn or not. Sims have connection to metro, connected devices do not. idk

Answer (score 1):

In my scenario, I needed to wipe my virtual device (AVD).
Steps:

1. Open AndroidStudio
2. I went into Virtual Device Manager
3. In the Actions column, click on the 3 dots and finally 'Wipe Data'.

Comment: Holy cr@p!  This saved me!  I've been working on this issue for hours.  Thank you - I wish I could give this more than one vote and move it to the top :)

Answer (score 0):

You musk permit local network in the application setting in iOS. Otherwise, Metro can not find your app even in the same network.

Answer (score 0):

For me the solution was to remove the installed app and build run in Xcode again.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, I had the same problem with RN - for me - there was a problem with connecting iphone to macbook server on localhost - and it solved if I just turned off wifi on macbook and then turned it on again. (Yes, it sounds weird - but it's a common problem)

Answer (score 0):

For me, on IOS, Xcode would be stuck in debugging, a breakpoint is active and Metro can't reload because no apps are connected. To solve this:

- open Xcode
- In the left-hand side panel, click from the top row on `Debug navigator` (if it's not already focused and in the view like it was for me)
- In the bottom pane (which can be minimized fully, in which case you have to hold and drag from the bottom of Xcode to expand it into view) you see a set of debugging buttons, the most left
  one is a blue arrow-head-shaped button that continues/unpauses the script, click it.

after unpausing the script my app would connect to Metro.

Answer (score 0):

Easy solution ->

1- Go to Developer options of your phone .
2- Disable adb authorization timeout..

Now reload project and enjoy coding..

Comment: I believe this is an android based solution. Need to specify when offering a solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you're on React Native 71 and using react-native-splash-screens, making your AppDelegate.mm like so

```
@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
  [FIRApp configure]; // If you're using react-native firebase

  self.moduleName = @"main";
  // You can add your custom initial props in the dictionary below.
  // They will be passed down to the ViewController used by React Native.
  self.initialProps = @{};

  bool didFinish = [super application:application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];
   
   [RNSplashScreen show];  // this needs to be called after [super application:application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];
   
   return didFinish;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, you get this error when one of the libraries defined in your code is not installed. This often occurs when creating a new environment and you forget to install one or more of the libraries used in your code.

Double-check each of your import statements , like the one below, against the list of libraries in the `package.json` file.

```js
import { abc } from  "@react-navigation/def";
```

In addition, you might need to clean the environment:

```
npm start -- --reset-cache
cd android & gradlew clean & cd ..
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I tried all the solutions suggested in the answers. My problem was that the app was getting disconnected from Metro after a few seconds of inactivity, as if it went to the background even though the app was in the foreground. The device was not offline, as confirmed by the adb devices result. I was able to load the app on Android, and after loading, the app stayed connected for a while.

This fix worked: I started logging using npx react-native log-android, and the phone stayed connected.

Answer (score 0):

I'm working with MacOS and using my iPhone conected via USB cable.

As many people said, wifi connection must be the same in both devices.
I was using a different one on my iPhone. I switched my iPhone wifi connection to use the same as my Mac but my app still wasn't syncing.

So I'm adding this step here which fixed the issue:

- turn off/on Mac wifi, and do the same on your iPhone just in case.

After I did this, it started working again.

Answer (score 0):

All my own doing as during some testing I had disabled 'Allow to access' > 'Local Network' in iOS settings for the app, enabling this again I was able to reload successfully as before.

Answer (score -1):

```
yarn start web
```

you can use this command to scan the QR code and see the app in you EXPO app at you mobile

Answer (score -1):

For iOS on Xcode:

Go to Window > Devices and Simulators, Go to "Installed Apps" section, Click on +, Pick your app , Run your code.

(This issue happened to me when I run the app after I uninstalled it from the device)

Answer (score -2):

My problem was that i added --variant=release

```
npx react-native run-android --variant=release
```

So i remove it and worked for me.Like this:

```
npx react-native run-android
```