# React-Native Run-Android Doesn't recognize Open Metro Server

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, metro-bundler

Issue: This broke with no changes between days. Even though I have metro running `npx react-native start` when I run `npx react-native run-android` it starts it's own metro server and does not allow me to do "fast refresh" it basically installs the debug build of the app onto the device. I need it to fast refresh for development purposes.
Already tried the steps on issue: [Unable to load script from assets index.android.bundle on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44446523/unable-to-load-script-from-assets-index-android-bundle-on-windows)

To test and debug my android build for a react-native project I had an emulator running in one Powershell window, would start a metro server in a second Powershell window using `npx react-native start` then run the app in a third powershell window using `npx react-native run-android` it would go through the build and install the app, then it would "pass" the app to the react-native metro server then that would install it to the emulator. This would allow me to make changes to the code and "fast refresh" the application in the emulator/phone and logs got outputted to the Metro Server.

Versions (executed at project root folder)

`npx react-native --version` : 6.0.0

`npx --version` : 7.18.1

Setup:

First Powershell window:
`emulator -avd Galaxy_Nexus_Android9 -no-snapshot`

Second Powershell window:
Make sure abd device is running

```
adb devices
```

result

```
List of devices attached
emulator-5554   device
```

run
`npx react-native start`

result: [Metro JS Server Start](https://i.stack.imgur.com/znHCN.png)

Third Powershell Window
run: `npx react-native run-android`

result: [Run Android](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PU4eM.png)

I boxed the line where it launches its own JS server instead of using the one that is open.

The app opens fine on the emulator (I initialized a new app to make sure there was nothing wrong with the app) [App Running Android](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eL3nb.png)

But on the Metro window, it did not install the app and when I try to reload it says it cannot detect any running apps [Metro Restart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1TEJV.png)
I've already tried the resolution here to run it on a different port with no success [No apps connected. Sending "reload" to all React Native apps failed. Make sure your app is running in the simulator or on a phone connected via USB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62937553/no-apps-connected-sending-reload-to-all-react-native-apps-failed-make-sure-y)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Solution:
Run the start metro server and run-android commands on a different port.
I suspect McAfee was using the default port 8081.

Open admin CMD/Powershell and run the following:

Reverse the port that the adb device will listen on:
`adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8090`

Start the Metro server on the same port:
`npx react-native start --port 8090`

Open another admin CMD/Powershell window and run:

Start the android build/run on the same port:
`npx react-native run-android --port=8090`

The last command should also start the emulator automatically.

If the metro server errors out after you do the run-android command, just run the `npx react-native start --port 8090` again in the same window.