# react-native cannot run android app from metro

Tags: android, react-native, build.gradle, metro-bundler

I am facing an issue with running my application from metro, which I need for debugging.

What I normally do and what also worked so far was to start Android Studio, then start an emulator. Do `adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081` to get it connected to the metro server, then run metro with `react-native start --reset-cache` and start the app from Android Studio.
I tried also this: [similar question already answered on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69215861/react-native-run-android-doesnt-recognize-open-metro-server)

Normally the app recognises the metro server and loads from there, unfortunately as of lately it does not, whichever build variant I choose.

There is no error, the app also loads, but since not connected to metro it is hard to debug.

My question is, is there any part within the build.gradle or anywhere else where I need to activate it and if so how does it normally work?

Comment: what error it throw?

Comment: there is no error - the app also loads, but not from metro although server and emulator seem to be connected