# React-native run-android command failed after i unistalled former app on AVD simulator

Tags: reactjs, react-native, android-virtual-device

I uninstalled the React Native app on my AVD simulator. I tried to run "react-native run-android" and I got this message in the console "No apps connected. Sending "reload" to all React Native apps failed. Make sure your app is running in the simulator or on a phone connected via USB"

I thought react-native run-android was supposed to re-install the app on the simulator. What can I do to have the app re-installed on the simulator?

Hi, Can anyone help me out?

Comment: try rebuilding it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to clear the cache

```
# Reset metro bundler cache : 
`npx react-native start --reset-cache`
    
# Remove Android assets cache : 
`cd android && ./gradlew clean`
    
# Relaunch metro server : 
`npx react-native run-android`
```

Or you can find you solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62937553/no-apps-connected-sending-reload-to-all-react-native-apps-failed-make-sure-y).