# network_security_config file causing issues in react native app

Tags: android, react-native, android-api-31

I have RN app (0.62.2) and now try to run in my Macbook Pro 2019 (Ventura 13).
I have file network_security_config and when I mention it in androidManifest.xml file
`android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"`

I am getting error in android emulator (PIXEL 5 API 30)

`"warn No apps connected. Sending "reload" to all React Native apps failed. Make sure your app is running in the simulator or on a phone connected via USB"`

And If I removed that line from androidManifest.xml my app keeps getting crash in both android emulator and in physical device.( without giving any error).

my build.gradle file

```
 ext {
    buildToolsVersion = "30.0.0"
    minSdkVersion = 21
    compileSdkVersion = 31
    targetSdkVersion = 31
    playServicesVersion = "17.0.0"
    multiDexEnabled = true
    kotlinVersion = "1.6.0"
}
```

Node version : 16.18.0
Npm version : 8.19.2

I tried everything mention in this stackoverflow .
[No apps connected. Sending "reload" to all React Native apps failed. Make sure your app is running in the simulator or on a phone connected via USB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62937553/no-apps-connected-sending-reload-to-all-react-native-apps-failed-make-sure-y/76407577?noredirect=1#comment134737873_76407577)

Still i am unable to solve this issue.