# Why does the iOS simulator not load my app?

Tags: ios, expo, metro-bundler

When I load Expo using `sudo npx expo start` in Terminal, and then type `i`, the iOS simulator loads the iPhone  home screen but the app isn't loaded. This happens with all of my apps.

If I type `r` to reload the app, I get the warning:

```
No apps connected. Sending "reload" to all React Native apps failed. Make sure your app is running in the simulator or on a phone connected via USB.
```

The QR code works fine on my actual iPhone device. It's just the iOS simulator that's not loading my app.

Environment:
OS: Mac OS Sonoma,
Node v20.11.0,
Expo: 60.0.3

Comment: rm -rf node_modules, 

npx expo start --clear

Comment: @MahammadMomin didn't work

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62937553/no-apps-connected-sending-reload-to-all-react-native-apps-failed-make-sure

please check this

Comment: @MahammadMomin why

Comment: same as your issues there in link please check

Comment: @MahammadMomin my issue is with the iOS simulator. You have directed me to an issue with a real iOS device. If you read the article in full you will see that I already commented on it last week